# flutter its correct on my android studio simulation but on the phone dont works correctly

Tags: flutter

on my PC my app works correctly, but when i build the APK and i install on my mobile dont works

On my pc i get the title of the API (simulating a android with android studio)

[image]

But when i install the apk on my mobile the screen of de title dont show nothing!

[image]

I try on more devices and i get the same error.

```
void main() => runApp(const HomePage());
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Youtube MP3';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: const FormularioYoutube(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormularioYoutube extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormularioYoutube({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _controller = TextEditingController();
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Introduzca Url de Youtube',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => procesarBotonParaDescargarMp3()),
            );
          },
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Descargar MP3', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class procesarBotonParaDescargarMp3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<YoutubeMp3?>(
            future: ApiRequest().YoutubeMp3s,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                );
              }
              final YoutubeMp3? yt = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(title: Text(yt!.title));
                  });
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the grey screen of death. This happens to me whenever I place an `Expanded` widget inside a `ListView`, or use a `Flexible` without a `flex` param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest. In debug mode Internet Permission is automatically set. It looks like it can't call the Api Request.

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```